# NotePad++ Как объединять 2 строки в 1 на протяжении всего документа?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

**У меня есть строки**

```
     Слово:
'Второе слово '
     Третье слово:
'Четвертое слово '
      Пятое слово:
'Шестое слово '
```

**И так на протяжении всего документа ~1000 строк**

Хочу получить

```
Слово: 'Второе слово '
Третье слово: 'Четвертое слово '
Пятое слово: 'Шестое слово '
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Заменой по регулярному выражению

Comment: Макросом первым и так далее То есть первую вторую Макросом далее остальные ...
Pr-t

Comment: Не знаю как, пробовал несколько раз. Но не выходит

Answer (score 1):

1. Найти: **`\s*(.+?\:)[\s\S]+?('.+?')`**

   - `\s*` - возможные пробелы;
   - `(.+?\:)` *- любой символы до ближайшего двоеточия включительно;*
   - `[\s\S]+?` *- любые символы (включая пробелы, переносы строк, табуляцию и тд.);*
   - `('.+?')` *- любые символы находящиеся между кавычек.*
2. Заменить на: **`$1 $2\n`**
3. Режим поиска: *Регуляр. выражен.*
4. <kbd>Заменить все</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
^\s*([^\r\n]+)\r\n([^\r\n]+)$
```

```
$1 $2
```

[image: скриншот]

Comment: [скриншот](https://i.imgur.com/6yuCZbC.png)
Возможно что-то не так делаю. Но все же.

Comment: Не так. Сравнивай.

Comment: Код , который написал вставлял через буфер обмена. Так что там ошибок нет. Но могу сказать, что \r\n у меня никогда не работало. ( Сталкивался с ним еще раньше )

Comment: 1. Ну так посмотри формат переводов строк в своём файле. 2. А "Заменить на" ты тоже копипастил?

Answer (score 0):

Выделить мышкой двоеточие, перенос строки и первую кавычку. Нажать найти и заменить. На двоеточие пробел кавычка. Заменить все.

Выделить всё и нажать несколько раз шифт+таб чтоб убрались пробелы спереди.